# Can plist files be used for holding large data such as image data etc

Tags: iphone

I want to use plist files to hold large data such as image data and other texts. Is this feasible or is it that plist are for holding small string such as needed for settings etc. Will there be any memory issues.

--
Regards,

U'suf

Comment: How many nodes you think your plist could have?

Comment: Hi,
 Thank you for ur reply.It can go upto 31 nodes or more..

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can serialize anything into an NSData and put it into a plist.

But a plist is more suitable to store changeable settings, not large binary blobs.

Answer (score 2):

Plists are indeed intended to store relatively small data. As an option you can save image to a file (it may be better solution even if you use database) and store path to the image in plist to load it from there when needed.